# CSS/HTML: How would I make these images horizontally-aligned?

Tags: html, css

The problem I'm having is that my social media images/links are being displayed vertically. I would rather have it be displayed horizontally.

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/JordanSimps/DQmm6/

---

index.html

```
<div id="wrapper2">
    <div id="twitter">
            <a href="http://www.twitter.com" title="Twitter" id="twit">

            </a>
            <a href="http://www.facebook.com" title="Facebook">
                <div id="ff">
                </div>
            </a>
            <a href="http://www.youtube.com" title="YouTube">
                <div id="youtube">
                </div>
            </a>
            <a href="http://www.vimeo.com" title="Vimeo">
                <div id="vimeo">
                </div>
            </a>
            <a href="http://www.addthis.com" title="AddThis">
                <div id="addthis">
                </div>
            </a>
            <a href="http://www.dribble.com" title="Dribble">
                <div id="dribble">
                </div>
            </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

style.css

```
/* Social Media Links */
    #wrapper2 {
        right: 34%;
        height: 10.850em;
        position: relative;
        float: right;
    }

    #twitter {
        position: absolute;
        list-style-type: none;
        bottom: 0;
        width: 225px;
        height: auto;
        overflow: hidden;
    }

    #twit {
        height: 32px;
        width: 32px;
        background-image: url(http://a.pictureupload.us/8067689795106d571328a7.jpg);
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-color: transparent;
        background-position: top;
    }

    #twit:hover {
        background-position: bottom;
    }

    #ff {
        height: 32px;
        width: 32px;
        background-image: url(http://a.pictureupload.us/12635610355106d56e2c160.jpg);
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-color: transparent;
        background-position: top;
    }

    #ff:hover {
        background-position: bottom;
    }

    #youtube {
        height: 32px;
        width: 32px;
        background-image: url(http://a.pictureupload.us/18402255565106d576a5d84.jpg);
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-color: transparent;
        background-position: top;
    }

    #youtube:hover {
        background-position: bottom;
    }

    #vimeo {
        height: 32px;
        width: 32px;
        background-image: url(http://a.pictureupload.us/11318810305106d57415681.jpg);
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-color: transparent;
        background-position: top;
    }

    #vimeo:hover {
        background-position: bottom;
    }

    #addthis {
        height: 32px;
        width: 32px;
        background-image: url(http://a.pictureupload.us/15195458355106d56859b0c.jpg);
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-color: transparent;
        background-position: top;
    }

    #addthis:hover {
        background-position: bottom;
    }

    #dribble {
        height: 32px;
        width: 32px;
        background-image: url(http://a.pictureupload.us/8852823855106d56b1b08a.jpg);
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-color: transparent;
        background-position: top;
    }

    #dribble:hover {
        background-position: bottom;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#twitter a { display:inline-block; vertical-align:text-top }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you just a little up with the div names (twitter seems to wrap everything else ;) )
 but the following works in the fiddle:

```
#twitter div {
    display:inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've added this to your StyleSheet.

```
    #twitter a{
        float: left;
    }
```

You can also make it float:right; depends how you wanna make it look.

Hope that helps,

Answer (score 0):

use float:left in all  tags and give a fixed width on the floated elements,then use overflow:hidden in the parent div twitter.

```
.twitter {
    overflow: hidden;
}

.twitter a {
    float: left;
    width:fixed width in px unit
}
```